# emacs: pad justified string with character

Tags: emacs, string-formatting

Is there an emacs command to pad a justified string with a character? Specifically, I'd like to be able to take

```
;; Foobar
```

and get

```
;; ===================================Foobar====================================
```

where Foobar is centered in a field of width 77. For clarity, I produced the output above via the python code `";; {:=^77}".format("Foobar")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any existing function to do that, but it's easy to write one:

```
(defun center-string-in-char (str len char)
  (store-substring (make-string len char) (/ (- len (length str)) 2) str))
```

Now `(center-string-in-char "Foobar" 77 ?=)` produces your example string (minus the leading `";; "` which you can add yourself).